# Hide table row based on contained td attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="xyz">Division 1</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="abc">Division 2</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Please note the `<td>` contents are added dynamically. I need to hide the second `<tr>` based on its `<td>` containing `<div>` class name. And please suggest in css/javascript method and no jQuery because the html doesnot support jQuery

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your javascript you have so far?

Comment: @user1782556 what have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont know, hence the question.

Comment: @user1782556 you were saying that the rows are added dynamically.. post the code you have for that so far so that we can build on it..

Comment: Its related to Vaadin - a java based component builder similar to GWT. Actually it reads the html template from a particular file which contains only the table definition such as empty <tr> <td> tags and the contents are added into <td> dynamically from java code. I can write the javascript/style script in the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/uaMxd/1/

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="xyz">Division 1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="abc">Division 2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    switch(tr.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).className) {
        case "abc":
        case "other div class names":
            tr.item(i).style.display = "none";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i<div.length; i++) {
  if (div[i].className == "abc") {
  div[i].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4QNBs/

**EDIT**

**For HIDE the parent tr**

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i<div.length; i++) {
  if (div[i].className == "abc") {
 // div[i].style.visibility="hidden";
      parenttd = div[i].parentNode;
      parenttr = parenttd.parentNode;
      parenttr.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4QNBs/3/

Comment: OP is asking to hide the `tr`, not the `div`s?

Comment: Actually I need to hide the parent <tr> not the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6HQmP/1/

If you want to hide tr, you should give related id to tr based on div, here i have give div class name as tr id

HTML :

```
<table>
 <tr id='xyz'>
   <td>
    <div class="xyz">Division 1</div>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id='abc'>
   <td>
    <div class="abc">Division 2</div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
var div_ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i<div_ele.length; i++) {
  if (div_ele[i].className == "abc") {
     // document.getElementById("abc").style.display="none";
     div_ele[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";

  }
}
```

If you cant give relative id to tr you can try this :

```
div_ele[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HQmP/2/

Comment: OP is asking to hide the `tr`, not the `div`s.

Comment: now you can hiding the tr either by parentNode of relative id to tr